# webgl camera top-view clipping my 3d cylinder

Tags: javascript, camera, webgl

This is related to my other post about the missing triangle because it is the same assignment, but a different issue. I'm trying to draw a 3d cylinder shape in webgl, where the top is thinner than the bottom. The cylinder is also uncapped. The cylinder is drawn using triangles for the sides, with a dodecagon (12 sides) as the circle. This issue is with a bird's-eye-view camera.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q2Bk.jpg

[image]

As you can see in the last picture, the outer edge of the cylinder is cut-off. I asked my TA about this, and he says it's due to me not using large enough values in my setOrtho and setLookAt functions. The vertices of my cylinder is at most 1 and at least -1 in the x, y, and z coordinates, which would mean my cylinder has a length of 2, I assume. Even with my setOrtho function parameters bumped up to 10, I still don't see a difference in output.

```js
var g_near = -10, g_far = 10;

  // Specify the viewing volume
  mvpMatrix.setOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, g_near, g_far);

  // Set the eye point and the viewing volume
  mvpMatrix.setLookAt(0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

my vertices:

```
var vertices = new Float32Array([ // Vertex coordinates                                                                         indicies
        0.0,   1.0,   0.5,     -0.25,   1.0, 0.433,   -0.433,   1.0,  0.25,     -0.5,   1.0,   0.0, // u0- u1- u2- u3  up       0, 1, 2, 3,
     -0.433,   1.0, -0.25,     -0.25,   1.0,-0.433,      0.0,   1.0,  -0.5,     0.25,   1.0,-0.433, // u4- u5- u6- u7  up       4, 5, 6, 7,
      0.433,   1.0, -0.25,       0.5,   1.0,   0.0,    0.433,   1.0,  0.25,     0.25,   1.0, 0.433, // u8- u9- u10-u11 up       8, 9,10,11,

        0.0,   1.0,   0.5,                                                                          // u12 up middle           12,

        0.0,   1.0,   0.5,     -0.25,  -1.0, 0.433,     -0.5,  -1.0, 0.866,      0.0,  -1.0,   1.0, // u0- u1- d1- d0          13,14,15,16, 
      -0.25,   1.0, 0.433,    -0.433,   1.0,  0.25,   -0.866,  -1.0,   0.5,     -0.5,  -1.0, 0.866, // u1- u2- d2- d1          17,18,19,20,
     -0.433,   1.0,  0.25,      -0.5,   1.0,   0.0,     -1.0,  -1.0,   0.0,   -0.866,  -1.0,   0.5, // u2- u3- d3- d2          21,22,23,24,
       -0.5,   1.0,   0.0,    -0.433,   1.0, -0.25,   -0.866,  -1.0,  -0.5,     -1.0,  -1.0,   0.0, // u3- u4- d4- d3          25,26,27,28,
     -0.433,   1.0, -0.25,     -0.25,   1.0,-0.433,     -0.5,  -1.0,-0.866,   -0.866,  -1.0,  -0.5, // u4- u5- d5- d4          29,30,31,32,
      -0.25,   1.0,-0.433,       0.0,   1.0,  -0.5,      0.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,     -0.5,  -1.0,-0.866, // u5- u6- d6- d5          33,34,35,36,
        0.0,   1.0,  -0.5,      0.25,   1.0,-0.433,      0.5,  -1.0,-0.866,      0.0,  -1.0,  -1.0, // u6- u7- d7- d6          37,38,39,40,
       0.25,   1.0,-0.433,     0.433,   1.0, -0.25,    0.866,  -1.0,  -0.5,      0.5,  -1.0,-0.866, // u7- u8- d8- d7          41,42,43,44,
      0.433,  1.0,  -0.25,       0.5,   1.0,   0.0,      1.0,  -1.0,   0.0,    0.866,  -1.0,  -0.5, // u8- u9- d9- d8          45,46,47,48,
        0.5,  1.0,    0.0,     0.433,   1.0,  0.25,    0.866,  -1.0,   0.5,      1.0,  -1.0,   0.0, // u9- u10-d10-d9          49,50,51,52,
      0.433,  1.0,   0.25,      0.25,   1.0, 0.433,      0.5,  -1.0, 0.866,    0.866,  -1.0,   0.5, // u10-u11-d11-d10         53,54,55,56,
       0.25,  1.0,  0.433,       0.0,   1.0,   0.5,      0.0,  -1.0,   1.0,      0.5,  -1.0, 0.866, // u11-u0- d0- d11         57,58,59,60,

        0.0, -1.0,    1.0,      -0.5,  -1.0, 0.866,   -0.866,  -1.0,   0.5,     -1.0,  -1.0,   0.0, // d0- d1- d2- d3  down    61,62,63,64,
     -0.866, -1.0,   -0.5,      -0.5,  -1.0,-0.866,      0.0,  -1.0,  -1.0,      0.5,  -1.0,-0.866, // d4- d5- d6- d7  down    65,66,67,68,
      0.866, -1.0,   -0.5,       1.0,  -1.0,   0.0,    0.866,  -1.0,   0.5,      0.5,  -1.0, 0.866, // d8- d9- d10-d11 down    69,70,71,72,

        0.0,  1.0,    0.5,                                                                          // d12 down middle         73,
  ]);
```

Comment: Do you scale the model? You're cylinder has the length of 2, if it is not scaled. If you've a scale of 10.0 then it's length is 20.

Comment: I dont think the model is scaled

Comment: Then why des the modell fill the entire disply with an orthographic projection from (-10, -10) to (10, 10)? Are you sure that the projection matrix is set?

Comment: I don't really know what a projection matrix is, but I found this in my code, which is from an example that I modified into my current program which displays the cylinder. the comments for this snippet says: "Pass the model view projection matrix to u_MvpMatrix"
`gl.uniformMatrix4fv(u_MvpMatrix, false, mvpMatrix.elements);`

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was that i was using only a single matrix, when i should have been using 2, and assigning setOrth and setLookAt to difference matrices